# How to trigger onClick and onHover CSS animation with ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, onclick, hover

How I can trigger the onClick and onHover CSS animations for the bellow ReactJS button component?

I've tried using ref = {input => (this.inputElement = input)}, but only clicked the button, no animation.

```
          <td>
            {this.state.buttons.slice(0, 4).map(btn => (
              <button
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(btn)}
                key={btn}
                className={this.getBadgeClasses(btn)}
              >
                {btn}
              </button>
            ))}
          </td>
```

I need this so that I can trigger both animations from a keyboard event.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tkkqx2y2/ this can help you to understand how you can solve our problem

Answer (score 3):

Basically, *onClick* works when you press the button with either mouse or keyboard (Enter or Space key).

When you move cursor over the button, the browser dispatches *onMouseOver* and if you focus the button using a keyboard, the browser dispatches *onFocus*.

It's very common practice to style *:hover* and *:focus* styles together. To add CSS animation to buttons simply pass *:focus* to it like below:

```css
.btn-classes:hover,
.btn-classes:focus {

}
```

However, if you want to add JS animation to the component, pass *onFocus* prop to button. The following may be helpful to you:

```
          <td>
            {this.state.buttons.slice(0, 4).map(btn => (
              <button
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(btn)}
                onFocus={() => this.handleFocus(btn)}
                key={btn}
                className={this.getBadgeClasses(btn)}
              >
                {btn}
              </button>
            ))}
          </td>
```